# The react input value is changed from disabled or readOnly to normal by F12

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Page rendering, input "readOnly" or "disabled" attribute is true.then I Press "F12",Remove the readOnly or disabled attribute manually.And then, I type in the text box.But it is not allow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is that a problem? react is not build for you to manually change html output? what is your problem?

Comment: How can I guarantee that the change of the page property will not change the input value, otherwise the user will save the errordata?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T prevent this behavior.
The HTML/JS are stored on your client and thus accessible and modifyable trought the web browser using F12, you cannot prevent the user from modifying your page using those tools.

It's your job to save the values entered by the user only when you allow him to input something in your textbox, keep in mind that thoses modifications are purely visual as long as they touch only the HTML part.

Comment: but like this `<input type="text" className="form-control" id="prectlid" placeholder="Required" value={data.value || ''} maxLength={100} disabled/>` ,when Remove the readOnly or disabled attribute manually. Users can't edit. But if this,`$("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", true);`,it can

Comment: @jiahangsu a user could stop all javascript/ or just directly call your api endpoint with postman and just send whatever values to the server the user wants. so you *have* to protect this at API level not in ui level.

Comment: @Joel Harkes What you say is also a thought.Thanks very much.